# styled components: how to select child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

```
// card.js

import styled from 'styled-components'
const Heading = styled.h1`
    color: red;
`;

const Summary = styled.p`
    text-align: center;
`;

const Card = ({className, heading, summary}) => (
    <div className={className}>
        <Heading>{heading}</Heading>
        <Summary>{summary}</Summary>
    </div>
);

export default Card;

// cardWithBlueHeading.js

import styled from 'styled-components';
import Card from './card.js';

const CardWithBlueHeading = styled(Card)`
    // How can I select the Heading component and make it blue?
`;

export default CardWithBlueHeading;
```

I'm trying to change the styles of a child component. These styles will likely be a one off situation. I'm trying to avoid selecting the HTML element `h1` and pseudo selectors.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass props to styled components like below:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
const Heading = styled.h1`
    color: ${props => props.color};
`;
```

Pass the color as prop

```
<Heading color='blue'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your Heading a `className` property and then select it with

```
const CardWithBlueHeading = styled(Card)`
  > .[classNameYouGive] {
    background: blue;
  }
`;
```

This is the standard css way.

Comment: what does '>' mean